# Curvature of a path

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that an object is traveling along a path $A$, and let $p$ be a point on $A$. If the object’s speed along the given path is doubled, what happens to the curvature of the path at $p$?

I answered the curvature doubles but the answer is nothing. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the curvature describes the *path* and has nothing whatsoever to do with speed.  So no matter how fast the object is traveling at point $p$, the curvature at $p$ is the same.

Just think of driving along a curved highway exit.  The curvature of the road (path) is literally set in concrete, and has nothing whatsoever to do with how fast someone travels along it.